# Dynamically select most recent table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to load some data into BigQuery every 6 hours, then later select only the most recent load.  Was thinking to do this with partitions but it seems like the only supported partition type is DAY, which won't work if I'm loading every 6 hours.  So, was thinking to create a new table every time the load job runs like this:

```
diffs_20191004T04
diffs_20191004T10
diffs_20191004T16
diffs_20191004T22
diffs_20191005T04
diffs_20191004T10
diffs_20191004T16
diffs_20191004T22
```

However, don't know of a way to only select the most recent table only with SQL.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It is news to me that BigQuery only partitions by day.  You might want to brush up on your knowledge of partitioning in BigQuery:  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables.

Comment: So in reading the link you provided I'm seeing that you can partition by ingestion time which automatically creates a TIMESTAMP value into the _PARTITIONTIME column which is a DATE.  The alternative style of partitioning is also based on a DATE or a TIMESTAMP, however, in reading the API spec to insert tables it looks like the TIMESTAMP must be a DAY: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#TimePartitioning Am I missing something that allows partitions by anything other than a DAY?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to load some data into BigQuery every 6 hours, then later select only the most recent load. However, don't know of a way to only select the most recent table only with SQL. **Is there a way to do this?**

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
DECLARE table_prefix, table_suffix STRING;
SET table_prefix = 'diffs_';

SET table_suffix = (SELECT REPLACE(table_id, table_prefix, '')
  FROM `project.dataset.__TABLES__`
  WHERE STARTS_WITH(table_id, table_prefix)
  ORDER BY creation_time DESC
  LIMIT 1
);

SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM `project.dataset.diffs_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = table_suffix;
```

As you can see from above - I am using newly introduced (actually yesterday) feature "Support for [**Scripting**](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting) and [**Stored Procedures**](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_procedure)" which is now in beta (as of October 2019)

You can submit multiple statements separated with semi-colons and BigQuery is able to run them now.

Comment: Wow dude that was magician level.  It's 90% of what I need, the only thing is that I'm using BigQuery Connected Sheets, which is alpha and doesn't support queries that return arrays/structs.  Since this appears to return two jobs the sheets connector can't handle it.  Is there way way to structure this so it only returns the query from the table with a suffix and not the query to get the newest table id?

Comment: there was not mentioning of using sheets in your original question :o(  you might want to post that new specific question as new post. meantime -  I think eventually Connected Sheets will be able to handle scripts - but as it is in alpha - you should wait for it unfortunatelly

Comment: Regardless of using sheets or not, is there a way to limit the number of jobs this returns?  I'm guessing not.

Comment: what you mean by "number of **jobs** this return"? please clarify!

Comment: Usually when I run queries in the BigQuery console (https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery), the results are immediately shown in the UI below the query editor.  However when running this query, the results are not shown, instead there is a table with a list of jobs: job 1 and job 2, each with a "view results" link.  Clicking on view results for job 1 shows the table id from the first query.  Clicking on view results for job 2 shows the results of the 2nd query (select count(1)).  I think this is why it's not working in Connected Sheets, it's expecting only 1 job to run from the query.

Comment: yes. read more about scripting :o) script is considered a parent job and each statement in it considered a child job. they all are executed as a part of the script. So behavior you see in UI is as it is designed by BigQuery Team. And that is what I meant by saying that most likely Connected Sheets will eventually be able to deal with Scripts :o)

Comment: Got it.  I think what I need is a solution that doesn't involve scripting.

Comment: Or (as an option) you can reconsider using alpha product in your production :o)

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a day partition, or even a month partition.

And you can cluster based on 5 columns.

You can do in the clustering the level of targeting that you want.